# I don't know why there are diferent numbers in the same variable

Tags: c

I was trying to assign in a 2D vector a random number between 0 and 10, but I kept having numbers above 10, (was an error of having different sizes of row and column), but searching I wanted to know if it was my fault or rand (wow mine), I changed the error, but i noticed that the random number assigned to "a" was different both times I printed.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
        
    int column = LENGTH/2-2;
    int row =WIDTH/2-2;
    int map[row][column];
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= row ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j <= column ; j++){
            int a =randint(11);
            printf("%d ",a);
            map[i][j]= a;
        };
        printf("\n");
    };
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= row ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j <= column ; j++){
            printf("%d ", map[i][j]);
        };
        printf("\n");
    };
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCdGT.png)

Comment: `i <= row` should be `i < row`, and the same goes to `j`. Arrays indices are 0..(n-1) where n is the dimension. You are accessing elements out-of-bounds.

Comment: `<=` is a bad idea for a loop counter condition when using C's "zero based array indexing".

Comment: OT: Adding a spurious semicolon after a close brace is asking for trouble... It's confusing when C++ class definitions require the semicolon, but this is C. What's between an open and close brace is a code block not a "statement" that needs the terminating semicolon.

Comment: @Fe2O3 No need to talk about C++ classes in a C question. The C `struct name { ... };` also needs the semicolon after the closing brace.

Comment: @mch Point taken... Without pretending to have a deep knowledge of syntactical analysis, there does seem to me to be a semantic difference between code that declares or defines regions of storage and code that is transformed into executable machine instructions. Like 'full stop' in a float or identifying a struct member, each character must be considered in context of where it appears. (My C++ 'dig' comes from past wrestling matches with that language... :-)